# Prove the energy $E(t)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb R^3} (|u_t|^2 + |\nabla u|^2)dx$ is decreasing.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\phi, f$ and $g$ are smooth functions with compact support in $\mathbb R^3$. Consider the equation: $$u_{tt} - \Delta u + \phi (x)u_t=0$$ for $(x,t) \in \mathbb R^3 \times \mathbb R$ and $$u(x,0)=f, u_t(x,0)=g$$ Prove the energy $E(t)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb R^3} (|u_t|^2 + |\nabla u|^2)dx$ is decreasing.
So we take the derivative of $E$ and we get $E'(t)=\int_{\mathbb R^3} -\phi(x)|u_t|^2dx$, but how to proceed since we don't know too much about $\phi$?